# Disable ping from a specific IP RHEL 7

Tags: linux, networking

I have requirement to block ping from a specific ip address in RHEL 7.

```
iptables -A INPUT -s X.X.X.X -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -d X.X.X.X -j DROP
```

I rebooted system, but still able to ping from X.X.X.X to my server. I have stopped firewalld service before setting iptables.

Comment: And you didn't even bother to [copy the formatting fixes I did on your Stack Overflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35979807/660921) or include the information that I mentioned... :-/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's crossposted from SO, and not a good question anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> Please advice

1. Rebooting is not required. In fact rebooting probably caused those rules to be dropped.
2. Read the documentation.
3. In most circumstances with a standardish set of rules already in place Use `-I` instead of `-A` - read the documentation to find the difference - order really does matter.
4. Read the documentation.
5. Test the rules then save them so that they are persistent.

If you want to block ping then you need to block ICPM message type 8

```
iptables -I INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -j DROP
```

If you want to block it from a spcific IP address

```
iptables -I INPUT -s 192.0.2.101 -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -j DROP
```